# How can I populate a combobox from a SQL Server database server in Delphi?

Tags: sql-server, delphi, pascal, delphi-10.3-rio

First of all, I'm new to Delphi, and I checked all the relevant threads on here, but nothing seems to be working.

I'm just trying to fill a `TComboBox` with values of a column from a SQL Server database.

So basically, I have a VCL form and a `DataModule`, which holds an `ADOConnection` and an `ADOQuery`. The `ADOConnection` connects to my database (test connection says it's successful) and the `ADOQuery` connects to my `ADOConnection`. The VCL form and the `DataModules` are "connected".

(And actually here comes another problem: whenever I'm trying to enter `SELECT name FROM Partners;` in the properties of my `ADOQuery` and try to set it active, it keeps saying "Invalid object name 'Partners'". The SQL statement is correct, I tested it in SSMS and it retrieves the data without any error. But I'm not sure if it's the main issue here).

So basically, here's my code:

```
procedure TFormInsertNewItem.ComboBoxPartnersDropDown(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with DataModule1 do
  begin
    ComboBoxPartners.Items.Clear;
    ADOQueryFillPartners.SQL.Clear;
    ADOQueryFillPartners.SQL.Add('SELECT name FROM Partners;');
    ADOQueryFillPartners.Active:=true;
    ADOQueryFillPartners.Open;
    while not ADOQueryFillPartners.Eof do begin
      ComboBoxPartners.Items.Add(ADOQueryFillPartners.FieldByName('name').AsString);
      ADOQueryFillPartners.Next;
    end;
    ADOQueryFillPartners.Active:=false;
    ADOQueryFillPartners.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Whenever I click to drop it down (or maybe it would be better if this runs when the form is loaded, but I have no idea how can I exactly refer to that event), it should fill it up. Well, it won't. I tried it with `TDBComboBox` and `TDBLookUpComboBox`, with setting their datasource, but it only added 1 item to the combobox.

Can anyone help me with what I messed up and how can I get it to work, please?

Comment: This is the wrong time to populate the combo box. The most severe problem is this: after the first invocation, `ADOQueryFillPartners.Free` will have made `ADOQueryFillPartners` a dangling pointer, so the next time you drop down the combo box, you will be using a dangling pointer. You should be using the form's `OnCreate` handler instead. Also don't forget to use the `BeginUpdate; try ... finally EndUpdate end;` pattern.

Comment: Invalid object means just that - for whatever reason a table or view with that name is not visible to the current connection. Wrong database or wrong schema is is often the cause.

Comment: This question is about populating a combobox from a query. If you have an additional problem, use the *Ask Question* button at the top of the page and ask about it there in a new post.

Comment: I was just mentioned that problem, because I'm not sure if that's related to the fact that I can't populate a combobox.

Comment: Well, clearly if you can't open the query, you can't fill the combobox from that query. If you open the editor for the ADOQuery.SQL property and put your SQL statement in there, and then set the `Active` property of that component to `True`, what happens? (Don't forget to set it back to `False` afterward.) If you can't get that to work, you've not set up the connection string properly for your ADOConnection.

Comment: I dropped a new ADOConnection to the DataModule (deleted the old one) and I now can set the ADOQuery active this time, so you were right that something was wrong with my connection, so thanks. But well... my combobox is still empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple problems in the code you've posted.

Clearly, the first thing you have to do is to get your query to open properly. If you can't run the query to get the data, you can't use that data to populate the combobox. Test your ADOConnection on your datamodule to see if you can connect to the database by setting its `Connected` property to `True`.

If that doesn't work, then you need to set up your `ConnectionString` properly. (Make sure you set the `Connected` property back to `False`. You should be connecting in your datamodule's `OnCreate` event, and disconnecting in the datamodule's `OnDestroy` event.)

If it does work, check to make sure you set the ADOQuery's `Connection` property to point to your ADOConnection, and then use the `ADOQuery.SQL` property to enter your SQL statement. Once you've done that, set the `ADOQuery.Active` property to `True`. (Again, don't forget to set it back to `False` and open it in your code at runtime.)

Next, you've used the wrong event. You should be doing this in the form's `OnCreate` event instead.

Also, you don't need both `Active` and `Open` for the query. They do the same thing; the only difference between them is that `Active` is a Boolean property that can be tested (`if Query1.Active then`) while `Open` is simply a method. There's no reason to open a query that's already active or make a query active that's already open.

In addition, you free the query at the end of your method, which means that the next time the combobox `OnDropDown` event is called, you're accessing an invalid class instance, which will cause an access violation.

And finally, you should be calling `BeginUpdate` before clearing and populating the combobox, and then `EndUpdate` when you're finished.

A more correct version of the code would be something like

```
procedure TFormInsertNewItem.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with DataModule1 do
  begin
    {
      I'm not sure why you're doing this at all. If you set the ADOQuery.SQL property
      at designtime, and it never changes, you can remove the next two lines.
    }
    ADOQueryFillPartners.SQL.Clear;
    ADOQueryFillPartners.SQL.Add('SELECT name FROM Partners;');
    ADOQueryFillPartners.Active:=true;
    try  
      ComboBoxPartners.Items.BeginUpdate;
      while not ADOQueryFillPartners.Eof do begin
        ComboBoxPartners.Items.Add(ADOQueryFillPartners.FieldByName('name').AsString);
        ADOQueryFillPartners.Next;
      end;
    finally
      ComboBoxPartners.Items.EndUpdate;
    end;
    ADOQueryFillPartners.Active:=false;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried it, but still no success, 0 items in the combobox.

Comment: See the comment I just added to your question above. If you can't open the dataset (the query), you clearly can't use it to populate the combobox. You should have asked a question about that problem first, before you posted this one.

Comment: @scratchingmyhead: See my edited answer for information about your database connection.

Comment: I could set the query active this time, but still not working.

Comment: @scratchingmyhead: The code I've posted works perfectly, if your query is active. I've used code just like it in dozens of applications in Delphi over the last 25 years. Did you remember to connect your form's `OnCreate` event in the Object Inspector  to the event handler I gave you? What happens if you set a breakpoint on the first line after `with` in the code and run the app? Does the breakpoint get hit? If not, you didn't connect the event properly. If so, single-step through the code using F8 and see what happens.

Comment: Sorry, I believe you and I really appreciate your help! 
I added the procedure to the object inspector OnCreate event. Set the break point, and out of nowhere, it keeps giving me acces violation errors (which is strange because I really haven't touched anything, I literally just set a break pont) and the breakpoint won't get hit.

Comment: Wait, it has problem with this line for some reason: `while not ADOQueryFillPartners.Eof do begin` at least, the debugger says so.

Comment: What *problem* does the debugger tell you it has? The debugger doesn't report problems. What **specific** issue are you having in the debugger?

Comment: I mean, when I start the debug, it shows the access violation error, and when I click Break, it jumps to that row.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on `ADOQueryFillPartners.SQL.Clear;` and hit F9. When that breakpoint is reached, hit F8. If you don't get an AV at that point, you can't get one on the `not Eof` line. If you get an AV on the `SQL.Clear` line, then you've got an issue where the `ADOQueryFillPartners` object has been free'd, and you're accessing an invalid pointer. Did you remove the code you had before, **and** remove the line that free's the `ADOQueryFillPartners` as I instructed?

Comment: Also, if `TFormInsertNewItem` is auto-created, the datamodule may not exist at the point this code is executed. If that's the case, use `Project->Options->Forms`, and move the datamodule to the top of the list in the right pane, above all the other items, using the buttons to the right of that list to do so.

Comment: I completely deleted my old code and copy-pasted yours. It gets an AV at the `ADOQueryFillPartners.SQL.Clear;` point. I also tried moving the DataModule to the right in the options, but I still get an AV at the same row.

Comment: Oh wow, I restarted everything and haven't touched the project,now it works. Thank you, you are the best!